# JSON Array into Mustache

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, mustache

I'm trying to get the data from my JSON array to be displayed in my Mustache template. I've been at this for hours, and I still don't know what I'm missing (or maybe have too much of?).

Please note that this particular task requires me to use `let` instead of `var`.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<script id="mustacheTemplate" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
<ul id="output">
{{#items}}
    <li>{{title}}{{description}}</li>
{{/items}}
</ul>
</script>
```

JSON:

```
{ "items": [
    {"title": "Mulan",
    "description": "Based on the Chinese legend of Hua Mulan, and was Disney's 36th animated feature."
    },
    {"title": "Beauty and the Beast",
    "description": "An adaptation of the fairy tale about a monstrous-looking prince and a young woman who fall in love."
    },
    {"title": "Aladdin",
    "description": "Aladdin is a street-urchin who lives in Agrabah, a large and busy town, long ago with his faithful monkey friend Abu."
    ]},
}
```

Javascript:

```
console.log($);


$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('../data/content.json', result);

    function result (data, status){
        console.log(data);

        let template = $("#mustacheTemplate").html();

        let content = data.items;

        let output = Mustache.render(template, content);
        console.log(output);

        $('#output').html(output);
    });
});
```

Comment: what's the problem here?

Comment: The list itself does not appear when I run everything.

Comment: i think you have missed ` } ` in your json

Comment: Kalaiselvan A I did! Thank you! But nothing shows up still. :(

Comment: is there any error? in your console

Comment: try this once to see if it is getting your array or not `{{^items}}
    <li>No Array</li>
{{/items}}`... if this loop works then the problem will be with your js code not mustache.

Comment: write this below your {{#items}}....{{/items}} loop

Comment: lakshay - tried it, and using Atom, the word "Array" is a different colour, but nothing appears when I run it.
Kalaiselvan A - no errors appear in my console

Comment: is it printing `no array` on template ?

Comment: no, it is not printing anything

Comment: @daezilla try `let content = data;`

Answer (score 1):

while passing render you need to pass your data instead of data.item

here I commented your  `$.getJSON('../data/content.json', result);`

It could be helpful to you

```js
function result (data, status){
      data={ "items": [
    {"title": "Mulan",
    "description": "Based on the Chinese legend of Hua Mulan, and was Disney's 36th animated feature."
    },
    {"title": "Beauty and the Beast",
    "description": "An adaptation of the fairy tale about a monstrous-looking prince and a young woman who fall in love."
    },
    {"title": "Aladdin",
    "description": "Aladdin is a street-urchin who lives in Agrabah, a large and busy town, long ago with his faithful monkey friend Abu."}
    ]
};
        //console.log(data);

        let template = $("#mustacheTemplate").html();
//console.log(template)
        let content = data;

        let output = Mustache.render(template, content);
        //console.log(output);

        $('#output').html(output);
        }
$(document).ready(function() {

    //$.getJSON('../data/content.json', result);

    
   result(1,5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script id="mustacheTemplate" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
<ul>
{{#items}}
    <li>{{title}}{{description}}</li>
{{/items}}
</ul>
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: thanks! I looked through your code, added `let content = data` to mine, and even tried the separate `<div>` with the `output` id, however it does not print anything

Comment: i thought you missed something in your code its works fine in above snippet right

Comment: yes it does, but my json has to be in a different file and not within the same function :/

Comment: your json data is the problem first you should fix that one and i mention it in above comment `}` is missing in your JSON data

Comment: I did add the `}` after seeing your comment

Comment: then what else? you are facing any problem?

Comment: ` $('#output').` won't be there  so nothing is printed

Comment: `id` is only in your template not in dom while rendering that why you are getting that

Comment: so I've tried `<div id="output">` and `<ul id="output">`, and still nothing. Sorry if this is frustrating you - it's been frustrating me as well!